# Applying multiple classes using ng-class

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

Assume that I have two objects in my model: `foo` that can take two values `Foo1` and `Foo2` and object `bar` with two possible values `Bar1` and `Bar2`.

Now, I would like to apply to my `div` classes based on values of these objects.
Basically, I would like to apply `MyclassFoo1` when `foo=Foo1`, `MyclassFoo2` when `foo=Foo2` and similarly for `bar`.

For instance, if `foo=Foo1` and `bar=Bar2` I would like to end up with

```
<div class="MyClassFoo1 MyClassBar2"></div>
```

The two problems that I am having here are:

- the class names are generated dynamically based on object values
- Foo classes are independent from Bar classes

I've tried to use the syntax

```
<div ng-class="{class1: expr1, class2: expr2}"></div>
```

but it doesn't work, as the dictionary keys cannot be composed as `'MyClass' + foo`

The other syntax

```
ng-class="{expr_val1: class1, expr_val2: class2}[expr]"
```

does not look promissing either: I would have to put all the foo-bar combinations as expression values.

Is there any other way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem entirely in template, using the list notation in the following way:

```
ng-class="[foo ? 'MyClass' + foo : '', bar ? 'MyClass' + bar : '']"
```

You can put arbitrary angular expressions into the list.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following?

```
<div class="MyClass{{model.foo}} MyClass{{model.bar}}">
```

Even if `model.foo` or `.bar` becomes `null` this will add a non-existing class, which should not matter.

Comment: thanks! many angular newbies overlook this and try to use ng-class

Answer (score 2):

Notice that if you want a minus (-) sign in your class name, you should quote the class name (check out 'second-class').

Also you can bind availability of the class name to a function. Function should return boolean.

```
<div ng-class="{first: hasFirst, 'second-class': hasSecond(), third: true, fourthClass: obj.property == value}"></div>
```

Comment: you're using static class names (first, second-class), while I need to generate them dynamically based on the object value (as stated in the question)

Comment: In this case you should use class="{{foo}} {{bar}}" instead. I haven't seen another way.

Comment: also you can make such constructions: <div class="{{foo=='val'&&fooClassName+' '||''}}{{bar&&bar+' '||''}}"></div>

Answer (score 1):

I've found another way!

```
$scope.foo = 'fooClassName'; 
<div ng-class="foo"></div>
```

gives you

```
<div class="fooClassName" ng-class="foo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, using array in the View:

just do:

```
<div ng-class="[class1, class2]"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this way and it worked but only drawbacks is it will not updates dynamically when you change the modules

```
<div ng-class="{'{{class1}}': expr1, '{{class2}}': expr2}"></div>
```